# how can I can estimate the standard error of the 0.1 percentile using the bootstrap?

Tags: r, statistics

I have calculated an estimate for the tenth percentile of the column medv in the Boston data set.
I want to calculate the standard error of the 0.1 percentile using the bootstrap. I have written this function to calculate it but It is not giving me the right value.

Can you show me a way to calculate the standard error of a certain percentile using bootstrapping?

Note: I'm aware of the package 'boot' but I want to use a custom function.

```
library(MASS)
data(Boston)
μ.hat0.1 <- quantile(medv, c(0.1))  

set.seed(20218)
boot <- function(times, data=Boston$medv) {
  boots <- rep(NA, times)
  for (i in 1:times) {
    boots[i] <- quantileSE(sample(data, length(data), replace=TRUE),p=0.1)
  }
  boots
}
mean(boot(times=1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

More concisely

```
library(MASS)
data(Boston)
μ.hat0.1 <- quantile(Boston$medv, c(0.1))  

set.seed(20218)
sd(replicate(1000,quantile(sample(Boston$medv,replace=TRUE),p=0.1)))
[1] 0.5209839
```

Comment: @Mo.Muse This answer gives you the standard error the 10-th percentile, are you sure this is your question? Why do you say it's not the right answer? Can you provide what the "right" answer is and how you obtained it?

Comment: Yes, my question is about the standard error in the 10-th percentile. The Right answer is about 0.488873. I obtained it using the boot function but I want to use a custom function to compute it.

Comment: @Mo.Muse But how did you obtain this number? Was this number also obtained through simulation? If so, you cannot expect the same result, even with the same seed, as the implementation could be quite different. If I increase the number of steps to 1 million the result changes to 0.5021308, which seems close to me.

Comment: I Used 1,000 bootstrap samples to obtain the number.

Comment: @Mo.Muse Then you cannot expect the same result, try increasing the number of steps and see if it approaches the result that I obtained with 1 million steps.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. It works now. Thank you

Comment: @Mo.Muse If this has answered your question consider accepting it to close the matter.